# Chinese Rings with recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

i want your opinion about my solution please.

I have to implement a recursive function which implement the chinese Rings game. this game consists in putting on n rings which are initially off. these rings are represented using a table (size=n). initially, all the table cells =0 and the final state --> all table cells =1. the exercice recommend the use of the "chinese" function defined as below to write the recursive solution:

```
chinese (t, k, b)
 {
   if (b) 
      replace(t,k)
   else
      remove(t,k)
 }
```

known that "replace" and "remove" function are mutually recursive."replace" puts all cells from 1..k on (t[i]=1) and "remove" puts all cells off (t[i]=0). so the solution which i propose is as below:

```
void main ()
 {
   int b=1;
   chinese (t, n, 1);
 }
```

and for the function replace and remove:

```
void replace(int n)
 {
   if (n > 0) // Do nothing for 0 or fewer rings.
    {
    replace(n-1);
    remove(n-2);
    printf("put on ring %d",n);
    replace(n-2);
    }
  }


void remove(int n)
 {
   if (n > 0)  // Do nothing for 0 or fewer rings.
    {
      remove(n-2);
      printf("Take off ring %d",n);
      replace(n-2);
      remove(n-1);
    }
  }
```

so what do you think about my proposed solution? thank you a lot

Comment: How many arguments? You have 2 at the beginning; 1 afterwards.

Comment: @pmg the table (t)  and it's size (n)

Comment: Assuming your code works the way you want it to, this would be a better fit on [codereview.se].

Comment: Is your _chinese Rings game_ this [**Chinese Rings** puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baguenaudier)? What do you mean by _putting on n rings_?

Comment: regarding: `void main ()`  (other than in the flaky visual studio) this does not compile.  There are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )` Note they all have a returned type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: in the function: `main()`, the variable `b` is never used

Comment: regarding: `chinese (t, k, b)`  This function is never prototyped, so will (at the least) cause the compiler to complain and most likely will not compile as the signature of a function must express the parameter types.  it should be: `void chinese (int t, int k, int b)`

Comment: OT: How can a item have less than 0 rings?

Comment: in function: `main()` the variables `t` and `n` are used in the call to  `chinese()`, but those variables are never define, initialized, etc

Answer (score 1):

Couple thing right off in main

```
 int main(void)
 {
    int b=1; // b is never used
    chinese (t, n, 1); // undefinef t and n
 }
```

Comment: int main(void)
 {
    int b=1; int *t; int n;
    chinese (t, n, b); 
 } is it ok ?